# Get back variables passed to jruby from java

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

This may be simple , I'll search for this but no luck

I have the code:

```
import org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
        int a = 1234;
        container.put("a", a);
        container.runScriptlet("a = a+10 ; puts a");
        System.out.println(a);

    }
}
```

You can see that ,the output from  `container.runScriptlet("a = a+10 ; puts a");` is `1244`
and `System.out.println(a);` is `1234`
Now i want the `a` variable must be change after run from jruby ,so that the 
`System.out.println(a);` should be `1244` 
How to do that ?

Comment: Try passing an object, such as Integer instead of an int.

Comment: Thanks ,I've tried but not work :)

Comment: Phooey.  The code I've implemented for calling Ruby scripts from a Java application and getting information back is under NDA so I can't share it and extremely complicated to boot because of all the class loaders, etc.  Have the Ruby script implement an interface, and then use org.jruby.javasupport.JavaEmbedUtils.rubyToJava to get the Ruby class and cast it to the interface, so that you can at least call a getter?

Answer (score 0):

Your example can never work as written. `int` is a primitive type and will be passed by value, not by reference. That is, the value 1234 gets passed to JRuby, not "a". You can easily see this by the fact that you can give the variable a different name in `container.put`.

If you want just a single variable back, you can [return it from your script](http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/embed/ScriptingContainer.html#runScriptlet%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
        container.put("a", 1234);
        Object v = container.runScriptlet("a += 10; a");
        System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

If you need more values, I'd recommend creating a simple bean that you can use to pass values back in an organized manner:

```
public class Main {
    public static class Values {
        private String name;
        private Long age;

        public void setName(String n) {
            this.name = n;
        }

        public void setAge(Long a) {
            this.age = a;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name + " is " + age + " years old!";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
        Values vs = new Values();
        container.put("values", vs);
        container.runScriptlet("values.age = 20; values.name = 'Tanya'");
        System.out.println(vs);
    }
}
```

As a third solution, follow the example in the [JRuby Javadocs](http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/embed/ScriptingContainer.html):

```
ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer(LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
container.runScriptlet("p=9.0");
container.runScriptlet("q = Math.sqrt p");
container.runScriptlet("puts \"square root of #{p} is #{q}\"");
System.out.println("Ruby used values: p = " + container.get("p") +
                   ", q = " + container.get("q"));
```